# Disable Session from Master Page

Tags: asp.net, session, master-pages

In ASP.NET, I would like to disable session state from master page, however @Master directive doesn't have EnableSessionState attribute as @Page does. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To continue where russau left off, if you need to be able to configure only a subset of pages, then you could use locational configuration to do it. You would need to put the pages that need to have session state turned off in a common location, then use the following (where path is ~/nosessionstate/):

```
<location path="nosessionstate">
    <system.web>
        <sessionState mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

If you are unable to group all of the pages together in a single location, you could have multiple location elements for each path. However, if your pages must be grouped with other pages that do need session state, then your only option is to configure it on a per-page basis.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would throw an "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level." exception if this path isn't configured as application in IIS.

Answer (score 2):

EnableSessionState needs to be done at a page level - as your masterpage will be used on many pages.

Do you want turn off session across the whole site?  In your web.config you can do this:

```
<sessionState  mode="off" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I don't want to completely disable session for the whole site. But just for some pages, which don't need it, as it will improve the performance. Btw I am using InProc mode; is disabling session for some pages that don't need it, going to better the performance? I am sure it will effect StateServer & SqlServer, but what about InProc?

Comment: I haven't tested the difference - but i'd guess it's a negligible improvment.